# Setting Up a Dynamic Stopping Point for a Loop

Tags: loops, stata

Data is setup with a bunch of information corresponding to an ID, which can show-up more than once.

```
ID          Data
 1            X
 1            Y
 2            A
 2            B
 2            Z
 3            X
```

I want a loop that signifies which instance of the ID I am looking at. Is it the first time, second time, etc? I want it as a string in the form `_#` so I have to go beyond the simple `_n` function in Stata, to my knowledge. If someone knows a way to do what I want without the loop let me know, but I would still like the answer.

I have the following loop in Stata

```
by ID: gen count_one = _n
gen count_two = ""
quietly forval j = 1/3 { 
replace count_two = "_`j'" if count_one == `j'
}
```

The output now looks like this:

```
ID          Data          count_one          count_two
 1            X               1                   _1
 1            Y               2                   _2
 2            A               1                   _1
 2            B               2                   _2
 2            Z               3                   _3
 3            X               1                   _1
```

The question is how can I replace the `16` above with to tell Stata to take the max of the count_one column because I need to run this weekly and that max will change and I want to reduce errors.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand why you want this, but it is one line whether you want numeric or string:

```
bysort ID : gen nummax = _N 

bysort ID : gen strmax = "_" + string(_N)
```

Note that the sort order within `ID` is irrelevant to the number of observations for each.

Comment: To match the example `_N` needs to be changed to `_n`. Please change and I will accept. FYI: This is needed when data is merged and their variable names are being appended with the string(_n) value to keep track.

Comment: Your question ends by asking for the _maximum_ and that's what my answer gives you. I see no reason to change my answer while that's the question.

Comment: For future readers, please also fix the mysterious reference to `16` as pointed out by @SOConnell.

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of your question aren't clear ("...replace the `16` above with to tell Stata...") but:

Why don't you just use `_n` with `tostring`?

```
gsort +ID +data
bys ID: g count_one=_n
tostring count_one, gen(count_two)
replace count_two="_"+count_two
```

Then to generate the max (answering the partial question at the end there) -- although note this value will be repeated across instances of each ID value:

```
bys ID: egen maxcount1=max(count_one)
```

or more elegantly:

```
bys ID: g maxcount2=_N
```

Comment: Last command won't work. Should be `gen`, not `egen`. `tostring` is less direct than `string()`.